# Why does not OpenURL work?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I create an ordinary game on android. I want to add some buttons with links to sites, but I have an error.

> ...\script\Application.cs(16,16): Error CS0117: 'Application' does not contain a definition for 'OpenURL' (CS0117) (Assembly-CSharp)

Maybe I need to add some libraries?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Application : MonoBehaviour {

    //Button
    public void SiteAction() {
        Application.OpenURL("http:// link");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UnityEngine** namespace already contains class with the name **Application**,
change your class name or call your method as shown below:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Application : MonoBehaviour {

void Start () {

}


//Button
public void SiteAction() {
    UnityEngine.Application.OpenURL("http:// link");
}

}
```